# Highlight occurrences in Jupyterlab 3

Tags: jupyter-lab

If JupyterLab contains this feature . It does have an opened issue :

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6112

Comment: My extension provides this feature: https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp

Comment: Thanks, Michał . I will try . Looks like the extension proposes many IDE capabilities